# Compare datetime object to Pyspark column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

Let's say I generated an epoch value to compare using datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
date_compare = today - timedelta(days=365)
data_compare = date_compare.timestamp()
```

I want to take this date date and compare it to a pyspark column that contains an epoch value which is stored as a long type.

```
+------------+
|date        |
+------------+
|1585872000  |
|1599321205  |
|1590710400  |
+------------+
```

When I try using a filter on my dataframe for records where the data value is greater than the date_compare variable, I no records return, even though I know that these values are greater than the date_compare. I tried going with this approach here:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.filter(f.col(date) > f.lit(date_compare)).show()
```

I've also tried converting this date_compare as a long time as well with a cast to see if that would help, but to no avail.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.filter(f.col(date) > f.lit(date_compare).cast("long")).show()
```

How should Pyspark intepret this datetime variable for me to pass this successfully to capture the records? No errors are returning when running this on my side so I cannot deduce the issue with this filter method.

Comment: `date_compare = today - timedeltda(day=365)` gives an error. 'timedeltda' is a typo. 'day' should be 'days'. The next line has an uninitialised variable `date_threshold`. have you tested the code?

Comment: @mck yes I manually typed this into stackoverflow. Thanks for the catches. Updated and added edits.

Comment: Then it should work now. To help you debug, could you post the output of `df.select('date', f.lit(date_compare)).show()`?

Comment: It actually works. Have you tried it? Maybe there is some other issue.  Here's a working code. I am using spark 2.4.4 
https://www.codepile.net/pile/Q3OOEX3A

Comment: I am not sure why it works now, when I was running the code it was returning 0 records. Sorry for this bad post.